# user notification while waiting

Tags: c#, progress-bar, notifications

I am writing a simple win forms app in C#. There is a method call in my method which loads files but is taking a while to respond. Below is the method call

**Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);**

I want to notify this to users.
Is there a way to show them that file loading is in progress? I want a simplest way.  I suppose Splash screen is too costly for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the application type (windows, web, ...) different techniques might be used. For a windows application you could use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. There are hundreds of examples over the internet, [here's one](http://www.dotneat.net/2009/02/10/BackgroundworkerExample.aspx).